# Highcharts Theming: How to set gradient colors for certain chart types only?

Tags: highcharts

I am working on building some charts in Highcharts with a custom theme. I've written a theme that rebuilds the color table into a set of gradients, and it looks awesome for the bars and columns. The only problem is that pie charts look like crap now.

Is there any way to set up a theme so it specifies a different set of colors for different chart types? I'd like to set gradient colors for just bars and columns, but I don't want to have to set these options for every chart I generate...

Example of what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/K7YPF/5/

```
var colors = ["#AFD8F8", "#F6BD0F", "#8BBA00", "#FF8E46", "#008E8E", "#D64646", "#8E468E", "#588526",
    "#B3AA00", "#008ED6", "#9D080D", "#A186BE", "#CC6600", "#FDC689", "#ABA000", "#F26D7D",
    "#FFF200", "#0054A6", "#F7941C", "#CC3300", "#006600", "#663300", "#6DCFF6"];
var gradientColors = [];
//rebuild all of the colors into gradients for the 3d effect
$.each(colors, function (i, color) {
    gradientColors[i] = {
        linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            y1: 0,
            x2: 1,
            y2: 0
        },
        stops: [
            [0, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.08).get('rgb')],
            [0.2, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(0.24).get('rgb')],
            [0.4, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.02).get('rgb')],
            [0.5, color],
            [0.8, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(0.12).get('rgb')],
            [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.08).get('rgb')]
        ]
    };
});
Highcharts.theme = {
    colors: colors,
    plotOptions: { // This does not work, but this is how I'd like to be able to do it.
        column: {
            colors: gradientColors
        },
        pie: {
            colors: colors
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: If you define colors by theme or using setOptions, then all charts will have this schema. In other cases you need to set colors for each chart separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#container").highcharts({
    plotOptions: {pie:{colors:[your colors here]}}
});
```